# Program to extract valid ips and valid ftp addresses

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm still pretty new in programming. I'm trying to write a code that can find all valid IP addresses and all ftp addresses in a text file and write only those addresses to an other text file. The informations i'm trying to extract are in a pretty big and unsorted file. Here's a few lines of that file without going crazy:

```
1331903561.260000   CptK3340W66OKHK3Rd  192.168.202.96  43740   192.168.28.103  21  <unknown>
1331905499.220000   Cup8D83JUM166udWb   192.168.202.102 4379    192.168.21.101  21  ftp password@example.com    DELE    ftp://192.168.21.101/.cache/    -   550 /.cache/.ftpduBnga4: Operation not permitted    -   -   -   -   -
1331905499.220000   Cup8D83JUM166udWb   192.168.202.102 4379    192.168.21.101  21  ftp password@example.com    PASV    -   -   -   227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,21,101,189,111). T   192.168.202.102 192.168.21.101  48495
```

The code I have gives me the informations I need but I am wondering if I can make my output more clean. My output gives me every ip in 1 line seperated with a comma. I would like to have 1 IP per line to make looking at it easier.

```
import os
from os import chdir
import re
import socket

chdir("filepath")
x= open('filepath') 

fichip = open('ip.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')
fichftp = open('ftp.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')


ipvalide = r"(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})(?:\.(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})){3}"
ftpvalide = r"ftp:\/\/(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})(?:\.(?:2(?:5[0-5]|[0-4][0-9])|[0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})){3}" #(ftp:\/\/)


txt = x.readlines()
ipmatch = re.findall(ipvalide, str(txt))
ftpmatch = re.findall(ftpvalide, str(txt))
in_listip = set(ipmatch) #not to have any duplicates ip
in_listftp = set(ftpmatch)#not to have any duplicates ftp

fichip.write(str(in_listip))

fichftp.write(str(in_listftp))

fichip.close()
fichftp.close()
x.close()
```

Comment: Please make a [mre]

Comment: I put all the code and data in one file and wasn't able to reproduce the issue, though I did need to remove the parens on `ftp:\/\/` to make it work properly.

Comment: I want to extract every ip adresses and write them to ip.txt. And after I want to take every ftp: //192.168.1.2 for example and write them to ftp.txt. In the text file I have, there's over 4500 lines. It's the reason I want to try and extract only what I need from it.

Comment: If you have found an answer it would be nice to post an explanation of what you fixed and how you made it work.